# ERROR(ORPSIM-16103): Invalid value when attempting AC Sweep in PSpice

Tags: error, pspice

When I attempt to run an AC Sweep in PSpice it gives me an error

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

Use VAC from parts list which is used for AC sweep

[image: Schematic]